# Why is the exception thrown "unknown message: class akka.io.Tcp$Bound" with case akka.io.Tcp.Bound?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

This is Spray 1.3.2, Akka 2.3.8, Scala 2.11.4, Java 1.8.0_25.

I am writing a Spray service. I would like to catch success/failure messages from `IO(Http)` with the following code:

```
def receive = {
  // Other case statements omitted
  // The docs say to use spray.can.Http.Bound which I tried and it does not behave differently.
  case akka.io.Tcp.Bound =>
    log.info("Bind successful")
  case m =>
    log.info("got unknown message: " + m.getClass)
}
```

At runtime I face:

> got unknown message: class akka.io.Tcp$Bound

Why isn't my earlier case statement catching this? What is the difference between akka.io.Tcp.Bound and akka.io.Tcp$Bound?

Comment: Because you have a case for the companion object of the `Tcp.Bound` class. Try `case Tcp.Bound(...) =>` or `case bound: Tcp.Bound =>` to match an instance of the actual class.

Comment: @jrudolph Mind converting the comment to an answer? Guess that'd close the issue (and you'd earn few points in the meantime! :)).